# Simulating the effects of external forces on a small population

Tags: simulations

I am looking to simulate the effects of external forces on a small population but I am having difficulty figuring out how I should go about doing such a simulation. My simulation consists of having small "atom" like objects that jostle about randomly and depending on the type of external force, the "atoms" will react differently. For example, if the atoms are introduced to a high viscosity fluid then "atoms" will slow down.

So, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I would like to add on that atoms and high viscosity fluid is merely an example. I am looking to model how say, people, would react to the introduction of money given people have some characteristics and money has some characteristics that would influence those characteristics.

Comment: @Glen_b I use atoms with quotes. I should have said people or something. This isn't a physics simulation.

Comment: Your model for 'people or something' is nevertheless a physics model - "high viscosity fluid", for example, makes knowledge of physics a pre-requisite for knowing how that affects particle movement. I remember a bit of high school physics and know enough mathematics to suggest some possible PDEs that particles in a high viscosity fluid might follow --- but if I was trying to use a model that was even slightly akin to "particles jostling about in a high viscosity fluid", I'd be asking a physicist how best to implement it.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry for using "high viscosity fluid". Since I was using atoms, I thought I should use something that would make sense in that context. If you substitute, for example, people then "high viscosity fluid" would change to say money. But you are correct, if this were related to atoms then it would make sense to ask a physicist.

Comment: Even if your model for people and money *is like a physics model* - e.g. based on PDEs, perhaps with notions *vaguely akin* to things like momentum and energy and viscosity - then you would still ask a physicist, because they solve problems like that all the time. They have the understanding of how to construct, simply and simulate models like that. If you want to ask a statistician, make it look like a stats problem! As it stands now, your question may be closed or moved.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. At what point can this be a stats problem? i.e. Would I have to provide some stats and ask a question about how to visualize or simulate that?

Comment: I'd start by discussing a model that looks more like a probability model. Discuss your important variables, any distributional assumptions (or at least some sense of the lines you're thinking along for them - what characteristics you'd want in a distribution), what parameters you have, any relationships between variables in your model, and so on. So you'd have some variable relating to how fast people are doing <something>, another relating to how much money there was, and so on. You'd describe which variables are random and which if any are not ... and how they are all related, if at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10220/discussion-between-gekkostate-and-glen-b)

Comment: I agree with Glen that this kind of "econophysics" requires at least a moderate understanding of the mathematical methods of physics. You won't reach a reasonable model for this until you understand something akin to basic thermodynamics.